# How to determine whether a function is n-linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Hoffman and Kunze's book on Linear Algebra, I struggle to provide a general proof of showing that a function is n-linear.

**According to definition in book:** Let K be a commutative ring with identity, where n is a positive integer. Let D be a function which assigns to each nxn matrix A over K, a scalar D(A) in K. We say that D is n-linear if for each i, $1 \leq i \leq n$ , D is a linear function of the i-th row when the other (n-1) rows are held constant.

For instance, in example 3: Let D be the function defined on 2x2 matrices over a commutative ring K with identity.

D is defined by $D(A) = A_{11} A_{22} - A_{12} A_{21}$.

Lemma: A linear combination of n-linear functions is n-linear.

Thus $D = D_1 + D_2$, where $D_1(A) = A_{11} A_{22}$ and $D_2(A) = - A_{12} A_{21}$.

Can someone help me to provide a rigorous proof on showing that both $D_1$ and $D_2$ are n-linear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment is $D_1\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right) = ad$. So, for linearity in first row, we have
$$D_1\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda a+a'&\lambda b+b'\\c&d\end{array}\right) = (\lambda a + a')d = \lambda (ad) + a'd =\lambda D_1\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right) +D_1\left(\begin{array}{cc}a'&b'\\c&d\end{array}\right).$$
Similarly for $D_2$. Hence, their sum is also $2$-linear. This also alludes to the well known sum property of determinant.

Comment: What do $\lambda a + a'$ and $\lambda b + b'$ imply ?

Comment: I wrote out how to check linearity in the first row. This is all by definition. Similarly, you check linearity in second row ($2$-linearity of $D_2$). @Bryanchan